# yii\base\InvalidParamException, http client, response, get parser(null)

Tags: php, yii2, response

Here is a stack trace from yii2 debugger

```
yii\base\InvalidParamException: Unrecognized format '' in /var/www/html/B/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/src/Client.php:178
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/B/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/src/Response.php(199): yii\httpclient\Client->getParser(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/B/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/src/Response.php(33): yii\httpclient\Response->getParser()
#2 /var/www/html/B/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(231): yii\httpclient\Response->getData()
#3 /var/www/html/B/common/models/A.php(327): yii\base\Component->__isset('data')
```

configuration of the http client

```
$client = new Client();
        $data = ['method'=>$method, 'params'=>$params];
        $encoded = 'Basic '.base64_encode('secret_key');
        
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setHeaders([
                'Content-Type: application/json;',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Authorization: '.$encoded,
            ])
            ->setMethod('post')
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setData($data)
            ->send();
```

when third party fails to response this code is crashing, i'm getting this kind of error only with one third party partner. i never faced this kind of issue. i thought for a moment that it might be yii2 problem!

Comment: Show your configuration of `yii2-httpclient`

Comment: is this enough, good?

Comment: check here `/var/www/html/B/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/src/Client.php:178` what data is expected and dump it.

Comment: can it be yii2 bug?

Comment: I am not familiar with this extension, but check this examples.. i think you have to set some format - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/tests/ClientTest.php